# Конкретный View в C-Objective

Tags: objective-c

У меня на данный момент есть 1 UITableView в проекте и такой код:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1;
```

}

Я хочу сделать несколько UITableView и применять свойства для конкретных, желательно по имени(id) интерфейса.

Вызывается табличный интерфейс строкой:

```
@synthesize oldtableclass;
```

Помогите реализовать функцию в первом листинге, используя конкретное имя интерфейса - oldtableclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю Вас это интересует?

```
if([tableView isEqual: oldtableclass]) {
    return 5;
} else if([tableView isEqual: anothertableclass]) {
    return 8;
}
```

Comment: совершенно верно ;)